# Twisted FileSender unable to send binary file due to UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, utf-8, binary, twisted

I have a rather annoying problem when trying to send a file via HTTP in Twisted. I'm reasonably new to Python (being that this is my first real attempt to do anything other than Hello World etc).

Now, I'm fairly sure that the problem occurs when the FileSender sends binary data that is not UTF-8 compatible. That seems like a fairly common thing to do when moving files like images, videos, executable binaries around over the network.

It would seem to me that when initialized, the Twisted buffer is initialized to `""`, which (I may be very mistaken here) is a UTF-8 (or whatever your Python's default character encoding is) character string?... Then, when new data is added to the buffer, the old buffer (UTF-8) is joined with the new buffer (er... some other binary encoding?) which results in:

```
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: exceptions.RuntimeError: Producer was not unregistered for /vfs/videos/thevid.avi
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 84, in callWithLogger
    return callWithContext({"system": lp}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 69, in callWithContext
    return context.call({ILogContext: newCtx}, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 146, in _doReadOrWrite
    why = getattr(selectable, method)()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 428, in doWrite
    result = abstract.FileDescriptor.doWrite(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 199, in doWrite
    self.dataBuffer = buffer(self.dataBuffer, self.offset) + "".join(self._tempDataBuffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 6: invalid continuation byte
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: exceptions.RuntimeError: Producer was not unregistered for /vfs/videos/thevid.avi
```

Surely there has to be a way to reliably set the buffer for binary data transfer? My code for the file sending function is below. I'm using TxJSONRPC to create and manage the server (except the `render` method, which is overridden to handle more than just RPC). If more information is needed (eg about the Request object or the Reactor, I can go digging).

Note: I'm well aware that I have no error handler, but at the moment that is of little importance to me. Error handling will be added once I get files transferring reliably!

```
def writeFile(self, request, location):
    # Setup headers (mime type, filename)
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', mimetypes.guess_type("file://" + location))
    request.setHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=" + path.basename(location))

    # Open file
    handle = open(location, "rb")

    # Setup transfer (then cleanup etc)
    d = FileSender().beginFileTransfer(handle, request)
    def fileFinished(ignored):
        handle.close()
        request.finish()
    d.addCallback(fileFinished).addErrback(fileFinished)
```

Comment: Please attach a more complete example, ideally something which you could actually run stand-alone (i.e. that connects to itself) so that I can see the bug, or at least say for sure that I don't see it.  For what it's worth, Twisted does *not* consider text passed to `write` or `writeSequence` to be UTF-8; they're just bytes, they're always bytes.  In fact they will raise a `TypeError` if you try to pass them unicode.  I have no idea how unicode objects ended up in `_tempBuffer`; it should not be possible.  So I can't really say more without being able to see *exactly* what code causes this...

Comment: Except that for a long time, writeSequence wouldn't check, so you could slip unicode past it.  The very most recentest version of Twisted will check in both places and so probably make the source of this bug easier to track down.